# How to make a timer constantly display

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I have made a chess clock but the time only updates when you click one of the buttons and I want it so the time is constantly updating. I have the setState() function after the button press but no ware else. How could this be mad to updating every 10th of a second or so. Thanks. Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

...
  Widget build(context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(// this is what creates the page, everything should be inside this cuz everything is inside the page
        appBar: AppBar(//what is displayed at the top WOW
          title: Text('chess clock'),
          
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(150.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState((){
                    if (button1==1){
                      button1=2;
                    
                      minus=minus2-minus;
                      fminus=fminus+minus;
                      
                      print(minus);
                      
                      
                      divid=DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch/1000000-start/1000000;
                      divid.round();
                      divid=divid-fminus;
                      minus=DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch/1000000;
                      divid=60.0-divid;
                    }
                  });
                  
                },
                child: Text(divid.round().toString()),
              )
            
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(150.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState((){
                    if (button1==2){
                      button1=1;

                      minus2=minus-minus2;
                      fminus2=fminus2+minus2;
                      
                      
                      
                      divid2=DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch/1000000-start/1000000;
                      divid2.round();
                      divid2=divid2-fminus2;
                      minus2=DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch/1000000;
                      divid2=60.0-divid2;
                    }
                  
                  });
                  
                },
                child: Text(divid2.round().toString()),
           ...
```

Comment: You need to call the Timer periodically and call setState. Have a look at [Timer.periodic](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html)

Comment: This is going to switch to button 2 every time that the timer updates. A chess clock is actually two clocks, right? Make the button click change the clock, create a two element array to hold the value of each timer, and update the timer function to count down the active clock. As written, button1 will take value of 2 every time the timer updates the clock (10 times a second). It will feel like tapping the button does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a complete solution, you should put Kauli's code in your initState() method and tear it down in dispose(). It would look something like this.

I've made some small changes to fit the needs of the solution.

**Edit**: I added the surrounding StatefulWidget class and removed some cut and paste which was confusing. You can wrap the build method with your original Scaffold and other widgets. I left that out to make the answer a little clearer.

```
class ChessClock extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _ChessClockState createState() => _ChessClockState();
}

class _ChessClockState extends State<ChessClock> {

  // Important to capture the timer object reference
  Timer chessClockTimer;

  Timer periodicSec()  {
    // How could this be made to updating every 10th of a second or so. 
    // Per op question
    return Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 10), (_){
      setState((){
        if (button1==2){
          button1=1;

          minus2=minus-minus2;
          fminus2=fminus2+minus2;

          divid2=DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch/1000000-start/1000000;
          divid2.round();
          divid2=divid2-fminus2;
          minus2=DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch/1000000;
          divid2=60.0-divid2;
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    chessClockTimer = periodicSec(); // Kauli's code 
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Stop the timer
    chessClockTimer?.cancel();

    // Clean up the timer
    chessClockTimer?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Your build method code
  }
}
```

Comment: As a matter of good style you should only wrap the minimum necessary in the setState() function body. Like "compute a bunch of stuff" followed by setState(() { divid2=60.0-divid2;}

Comment: If you like the answer please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Timer.periodic to do this

```dart
void periodicSec()  {
  Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_){
    setState((){
      if (button1==2){
        button1=1;

        minus2=minus-minus2;
        fminus2=fminus2+minus2;



        divid2=DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch/1000000-start/1000000;
        divid2.round();
        divid2=divid2-fminus2;
        minus2=DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch/1000000;
        divid2=60.0-divid2;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I've expanded on @kauli's solution in my answer. I wish SO allowed credit sharing. This answer strictly answers the op question, but mine gives it in a more complete context.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help but my friend and I don't understand what you did to the top of the class so can you give us a little bit of code that you would put and the top to call the class? Thanks

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Like the complete Widget if it's small enough? I assumed you were doing this inside of a StatefulWidget.

Comment: import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() {

      return  _MyAppState();
    }
}
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{
  
  int start=DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch;
  double divid=0.0;
  double divid2=0.0;
  double minus=DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch/1000000;
  double minus2=DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch/1000000;
  double fminus=0.0;
  double fminus2=0.0;
  int button1 = 1;
  double starttime=60.0;

Comment: is that readable       Here is a link: https://ctxt.io/2/AABgEVAAEw

Comment: I've edited my answer. You can edit your question to add this code and then you can format it better.